# CiviCRM Report only showing 50 records

Tags: civicontribute, civireport, reports, donations

Do anyone else have Donation Reports that only show 50 records on the webpage but when you export it shows all of them? There is no pagination and looking at the demos, it looks like there should be.

CiviCRM: 5.18.2 Drupal: 7.67 MySQL: 5.7.27 PHP: 7.2.22

Comment: perhaps add a link to the report on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org so folk are looking at the same thing you are - also confirms the issue you are seeing is generic and not something specific to yours

Comment: The contribution summary shows only 50 rows and no paging in 5.15.2 but you can export the whole report which might be many more rows.  Is this a WAD or a bug?  Maybe that's the question?  I don't see this in other contribution reports.

Comment: Andy this is exactly what I have to do. I’m only seeing it on the Contribution Summary report. Contribution Detail show pagination. 

I was able to replicate issue on dmaster, just change grouping to Contact Name only: https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/7

Comment: Looks like 'as designed' to me, but I will ask on chat.civicrm.org

Comment: A comment from Eileen on chat.civicrm.org "oh @vangelisp had an issue on this - I actually did figure out the answer - we could fix that - possibly in the rc" So looks like an issue - if I can find the issue number I'll post it as an answer

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!